# Converting maven code generation to gradle task

Tags: maven, gradle, wsdl, code-generation, wsdl2java

I am looking to convert axis2 plugin code generation to gradle. Any help appreciated.
We are using apache axis 2 client. But our application in gradle. Trying to create a taskGen in gradle. But I stuck with where i will start. I am not that much aware of groovy task generators.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</sourceDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>my_service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1):

Gradle has native support for invoking ant tasks so you could use the [axis ant tasks](https://axis.apache.org/axis/java/ant/ant.html)

See the [Gradle Ant docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/ant.html)

You can also [search the plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=axis) which seems to have a handful of plugins mentioning axis / wsdl